# Google Places API bounds in http request

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

Is it possible to limit the search area for Google Places in an http request? The website mentions bounds are possible (using SW and NE lat and long for the corners) for the javascript method but I would like to stick to the http request because I know nothing about javascript. Any help would be really appreciated because I am struggling with this. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, your http request should be something similar to this:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/output?parameters
```

There are a required set of parameters, including the `radius` parameter (unless `rankby=distance` is set) that need to be used with the places api. The radius parameter is what you are looking for, the maximum allowed value is 50,000. The units are in meters, so the maximum distance would be 50km.

An example http api call would look something like this:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere
```

This will output the requested places of type 'food' within a 500m radius of a point in Sydney, Australia, containing the word 'harbour' in their name. The data will be returned in the Json format. You may be working with XML data instead of Json, if that's the case then just replace `json` with `xml` in the http request.

More information on using the Places API can be found [Here](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search).

Comment: Thank you. I've been using the radius but now I realized I have to search within a box because I am searching for places within a camera view...Maybe I can use the radius and just take a pie slice out and search in there

Comment: The places api uses the `radius` parameter to determine the distance from the center point, to specify a box search area, you could analyze the longitude/latitude of the returned place, based on the location you could determine whether it is inside the box you are looking for.